# Text file with and without delimiters to be converted to pandas dataframe with column headers

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, text, format

A text file was sent to me that have some tab delimiters, columns are combined with no spaces - the file does not have any headers. I'm attempting to create the appropriate columns in a panda dataframe. The code below did help but it is not quite getting me the final state. I'm struggling with this and would appreciate any help.

Original .txt file

```
 2003040201629002A09/01/201920030001708534AGMT    11/10/199900000000045000.0006/13/2003                       
 00000000000008/16/201900000000000000                                                                                                          
 2003040201629002L4011470033NENND131-48       77TH   STREET                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 2003040201629002P1LIWANAG, MARIVIN                                                      3148 77TH STREET                                                                                                        USJACKSON HEIGHTS               NY113701825
 2003040201629002P1MAQUIRAN, JUDY                                                        3148 77TH STREET                                                                                                        USJACKSON HEIGHTS               NY113701825
 2003040201629002P2JPMORGAN CHASE BANK                                                   ONE CHASESQUARE S-4                                                                                                    USROCHESTER                     NY14643
```

Desired Format

```
Doc_id            Document_date BankName            PartyName        Street#  StreetName city st zip
2003040201629002A 09/01/2019    JPMORGAN CHASE BANK LIWANAG, MARIVIN 131-48  77TH STREET JACKSON HEIGHTS NY14643
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd

my_cols = [str(i) for i in range(9)]
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/smorris/python/201908_Monthly.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, names=my_cols) 

df['state'] = df['8'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)') #
df['zip_code'] = df['7'].str.extract('([0-9]+)') #
df['date'] = df['0'].str.extract("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})", expand=True)
```